# Counting rows conditionally by date within a group in SSRS?

Tags: reporting-services

I'm trying to to count the number of rows within a group that meet a certain criteria in SSRS.

In my Tablix; i have a category group. Within this category group there is a Create_date column. I want to count the number of rows within the group where the Create_date is within the current month.

```
=SUM(IIF(ReportItems!Inital_Date.Value > 
DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, Today()), 0) 
AND ReportItems!Inital_Date.Value > 
DATEADD(dd,-1,DATEADD(mm,1,DATEADD(mm, DATEDIFF(mm,0, Today()), 0)))
, 1, 0))
```

I've also tried to specify Fields! instead of ReportItems!; I think i need to properly specify the scope of the group perhaps?

This gives me an error:
*Aggregate functions can be used only on report items contained in page headers and footers.*

I've included an image of my tablix layout as well.

[image: Tablix Layout]

Comment: `Initial_Date` is coming from a dataset?  Or that's the name of a textbox?

Comment: It is a field in the dataset

Comment: And what error do you get when you use `Fields!Initial_Date.Value`?

Answer (score 0):

I can;t test this at the momeent but if you simply want to test against the current month then you could simplify the expression as

```
=SUM(IIF(MONTH(Fields!Initial_Date.Value) = MONTH(Today()),1,0))
```

The scope will be the same scope as you put the expression, so if it's within a row group, the SUM will operate against all the rows with in that rowgroup, this is the default behavior.

Answer (score 0):

in your expression amend to show:

=IIF(MONTH(Fields!Initial_Date.Value) = MONTH(Today()) AND (YEAR(Fields!Initial_Date.Value) = YEAR(Today()))  , 1 ,0)